# Qt Creator + CMake + Clang

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, qt-creator

I am trying to use Qt Creator to work on a non-Qt C++ program, built using CMake with Clang as the compiler. Platform is Windows 10 64. All versions are most recent at time of this post. After manually downloading Jom and adding it to the path, I get this error trying to build a Hello World program:

```
The C compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0
The CXX compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang-cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-zKOojN/qtc-cmake-TXXABrTJ/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"jom" "/nologo" "cmTC_75f57\fast"
    jom: parallel job execution disabled for Makefile
        C:\apps\Jom\jom.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_75f57.dir\build.make /nologo -L CMakeFiles\cmTC_75f57.dir\build
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_75f57.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
        C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe @C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\testCCompiler.c.obj.12652.16.jom
    Linking C executable cmTC_75f57.exe
        "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_75f57.dir --manifests  -- llvm-ld /nologo @CMakeFiles\cmTC_75f57.dir\objects1.rsp @C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\cmTC_75f57.exe.12652.297.jom
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /foCMakeFiles\cmTC_75f57.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_75f57.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the file specifiedjom: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\QtCreator-zKOojN\qtc-cmake-TXXABrTJ\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CMakeFiles\cmTC_75f57.dir\build.make [cmTC_75f57.exe] Error 2
    jom: C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\QtCreator-zKOojN\qtc-cmake-TXXABrTJ\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Makefile [cmTC_75f57\fast] Error 2
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET (CMAKE_C_COMPILER             "clang-cl")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS                "-Wall -std=c99")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG          "-g")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL     "-Os -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE        "-O4 -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g")

SET (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER             "clang-cl")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS                "-Wall")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG          "-g")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL     "-Os -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE        "-O4 -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g")

SET (CMAKE_AR      "llvm-ar")
SET (CMAKE_LINKER  "llvm-ld")
SET (CMAKE_NM      "llvm-nm")
SET (CMAKE_OBJDUMP "llvm-objdump")
SET (CMAKE_RANLIB  "llvm-ranlib")

project(TestProg)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
```

Comment: How did you configure your Kits? Does clang show up there?
You should not set the compiler manually in the CMake file, cmake will pick it up from the kit you have chosen to configure the project with. Also, it's good advice to always delete the CMakeCache.txt after changing something or you might run into unexpected and hard to explain trouble.

Comment: Do you by chance clear the build environment in your project settings? http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-build-settings.html#build-environment